# Java Initiate Subclass Instances with Superclass Instance Data

Tags: java, android

I have a class `FavoriteInfo` that stores user favorites. It has a bunch of private fields and public gets:

```
public class FavoriteInfo implements Serializable {         
    public static String KEY ="FavoriteInfo";

    private String favtype;
    private String rdbkey;

    private String VideoURL;
    private String ImageURL;
    private Float Temperature;
    /* more such fields */

    public String getFavtype() {
        return favtype;
    }

    public void setFavtype(String favtype) {
        this.favtype = favtype;
    }

    public String getRdbkey() {
        return rdbkey;
    }

    public void setRdbkey(String rdbkey) {
        this.rdbkey = rdbkey;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return ImageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.ImageURL = imageURL;
    }
```

Then I have:

```
public abstract class MomentData extends FavoriteInfo {
    public static final int DATA_TYPE_IMAGE = 0;
    public static final int DATA_TYPE_VIDEO = 1;

    public abstract int getDataType();
    public abstract View getChildView(Context context,View convertView, ViewGroup parent);
}
```

And two public classes `MomentImageData` and `MomentVideoData` that extend MomentData.

My data comes from a HTML request that directly populates the fields in `FavoriteInfo` and returns a **List** of `FavoriteInfo` instances. This is the data source that I want to keep untouched and tap into. I don't have any additional fields except for `DATA_TYPE_IMAGE` and `DATA_TYPE_VIDEO` in the subclasses.

My question is how I can use this list to build a list of `MomentImageData` and a list of `MomentVideoData`?

This is what I want to achieve:

```
List<MomentData> mData;
List<MomentImageData> imgData; // from one source 
List<MomentVideoData> videoData; // from another

mdata.addAll(imgData);
mdata.addAll(videoData);
```

This may look weird, but it's actually an Android app and I have a custom adapter that takes `MomentData mData` as the data source, and then it inflates different views based on the type (image or video) dynamically.

Comment: Not really clear what you want to accomplish. Anyway, why do you need `DATA_TYPE_IMAGE` when you have an extra class (type) `MomentImageData` for this ?

Comment: @PeterMmm updated question.

Comment: I assume that in a `FavoriteInfo` you receive, _either_  `VideoURL` _or_ `ImageURL` is set. Is that true?

Comment: Change your type declaration: `List<? extends MomentData> mData;`. Then you can add objects whose class extends MomentData, not just objects whose class is exactly MomentData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most directly way to create a sub-class instance from a super-class instance is by copying the fields from the super-class instance into the sub-class instance

```
public MomentImageData(FavoriteInfo info) {
    setRdbkey(info.getRdbkey());
    // ... and all the others
}
```

An alternative is to use reflection or a deep-copy library to save you from writing all this setters.

Java won't do this four you, because a MomentImageData is a FavoriteInfo but not
viceversa.

Another way is to use composition and not inheritance:

```
public class MomentImageData {
     FavoriteInfo info;

     public MomentImageData(FavoriteInfo info) {
          this.info = info;
     }
}
```

So you can easily create an instance like

```
List<FavoriteInfo> list = new ArrayList();
// fill the list
MomentImageData mid = new MomentImageData(list.get(1));
```

Comment: Actually I have a List<MomentData>. I want to populate MomentImageData and MomentVideoData separately and add them to my list. That's why I have this inheritance structure. You can see my updated description. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And even if the fields in class FavoriteInfo are all private, you acn still set them in the subclass and get them in the subclass? Thanks.

Comment: Because I think private fields won't be inherited by subclasses.

Comment: Your question and above comments are not clear. Do you receive a `List<FavoriteInfo>` or `List<MomentData>` ? then what is the actual type of the elements in the list ? you can have a `List<FavoriteInfo>` and each object in the list is an instance of `MomentImageData` or `MomentVideoData`, or just a plain instance of `FavoriteInfo`. All this can make a difference on how to solve your problem.

Comment: @AbbéRésina I receive a List<FavoriteInfo>. The actual type is type FavoriteInfo.

Comment: It seems the implementation is a deep copy, but I actually don't need to modify the data, so can you throw some light on how to make a shallow copy? Thanks.